# What is the name (in 普通话) of a card game known as "three card brag"?

Tags: culture, games

I heard of this game "three card brag"  - didn't quite catch the name? Also - is there a place that states the rules that you could reference me to? 多谢 ：）

我喜欢中国的纸牌游戏！ 特别斗地主。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_card_brag

'brag' meaning exaggerate, pretend you have really good cards.

晓云说了是‘炸金华‘=
Xiaoyun said it is ‘炸金华‘

Comment: Thank you :) Do you know the Chinese name for it perchance?

Comment: 扎金花，or 诈金花 also called 三张牌